# How to properly encrypt/decrypt Core Data on iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, encryption, core-data

I'm new to the iOS development. I have a local SQLite database, which is using Core Data. I'd like to encrypt this database, so in the case when someone retrieves the file with the database from the iPhone device, it wouldn't be possible to read its contents. I found several solutions (including StackOverflow threads) and third-party libraries, but they don't work or they don't support functionalities I'm using (e.g. batch delete). I also could not find relevant information in the official documentation. Could you please, provide a complete example of encryption of the SQLite database with Core Data on iOS with Swift or give me some hints or resources how can I do that? I appreciate your answers.

I'm initializing database in the following way:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: DatabaseManager.self)
let modelUrl = bundle.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "momd")!
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl)!
persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName, managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in

if let error = error as NSError? {
  FrameworkLogger.error("Unresolved error \(String(describing: error)), \(error.userInfo)")
}

context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
```

How can I add encryption to this code?

Regards,

Piotr

Comment: In IOS, Even if you don't Encrypt data, Your data are safe, No one can restrive it until they do the jailbreaking of the iPhone..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read in the Apple Developer documentation that since iOS 5.0 data is encrypted by default.